# Как с помощью flex-box, один контейнер оставить по центру а второй прижать к полу

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Всем привет, хороших выходных.
Ребя, чет торможу жуть, вчера весь вечер промчался.
Ну можно же через margin-top: auto;  - прижать элемент к полу.
Но у меня такая история.
(Вот ссылка на пример: https://codepen.io/pipskvik/pen/rNOarxb).
HTML:

```
<main>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="block1">Any text Any text Any text Any text Any text Any text Any text Any text Any text </div>
    <div class="block2">Any text Any text Any text Any text Any text Any text Any text Any text Any text </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap {
  width: 1000px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #999fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.block1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: salmon;
  margin: 10px;
}

.block2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

У меня есть страничка, во весь вьюпорт фотка - это мэйн контейнер.
Далее идет 2 блока, 1- заголовок, который должен быть по центру, а внизу кнопочки слайдера.
Ну и как-то можно flexom оставить заголовок по центру, а кнопоньки с каким-то отступом прижать в низу?)
Буду рад помощи)))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

смотреть на весь экран

```css
.wrap {
  width: 1000px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #999fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.block1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: salmon;
  align-content: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.block2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  align-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="block1">Any text Any text Any text Any text Any text Any text Any text Any text Any text </div>
    <div class="block2">Any text Any text Any text Any text Any text Any text Any text Any text Any text </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Максим, спасибо большое. Ты гений, очень круто робит.
Взял на заметку))))
Очень спасибо, хорошего дня!!!!